# How dose the command line prediction work in typical routers?

Tags: command

Anybody, who does some command in typical routers like cisco or junper, would know when you type commands, there is 'tab completion' for every level of one command, and if you type '?', you also can see the possible options.

How do they implement it? I want to make a similar one. Can anybody please give me some clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question is stupid. I just suddenly remember one very usual way to implement this. Any language with the interface to use stdin can do the job.